# Evaluate $\sin[\pi/2-\sin^{-1} (-1/2)]$

Tags: inverse

[image: Question]

[image: My solution]

My answer isn't even in options. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting I am unable to get it look inverse

Comment: You can use a calculator and verify what is the correct answer.

Comment: Try showing your work in MathJax. If you make a start, we can improve it for you. For example, look at the edited title to see how to do $\sin$ and $\cos$, and you can use `$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$` to get $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Feel free to ask any questions about MathJax.

Comment: Ok understood, Thank You

Comment: How to get inverse sign using MathJax

Comment: `$\sin^{-1}$` gives you $\sin^{-1}$. ¶ Incidentally, I also get $\sqrt{3}/2$, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @BrianTung I guess, there's no point in wasting time over whacky typos. Calculators say the same.

Comment: @Nothingspecial: No, but it's worth pointing out to the OP that they don't seem to be missing some subtlety that causes them to waste time.

Comment: So  options are wrong?

Comment: Seems like it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28pi%2F2-arcsin%28-1%2F2%29%29

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. It is one of the most popular question banks in India but still they make many mistakes

Comment: @BrianTung Agreed, so we can just let them know, their evaluation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an typo in the question. I google it and find "CBSE Sample Paper 2021-22". The [correct question](https://cbseacademic.nic.in/web_material/SQP/ClassXII_2021_22/Maths-SQP.pdf) is: [image]

Now you can solve it.

$$\sin\left[\frac{\pi}3-\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}2\right)\right]{=\sin\left[\frac{\pi}3+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}2\right)\right]\\
=\sin\left[\frac{\pi}3+\frac{\pi}6\right]\\
=\sin \frac{\pi}{2}=1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The set of all angles $\theta$ for which $\sin \theta = -\frac{1}{2}$ is $$\theta \in \left\{\ldots, -\frac{17\pi}{6}, -\frac{13\pi}{6}, -\frac{5\pi}{6}, -\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{7\pi}{6}, \frac{11\pi}{6}, \ldots \right\}  = \left\{-\frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi k, -\frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi k\right\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}.$$  So the set $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$ is just
$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta = \left\{\pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi k \right\}_{k \in \mathbb Z}.$$
Consequently
$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = \pm \sin \frac{\pi}{3} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ neither of which is among the included answer choices.

Comment: But I had in mind that by definition, $|\sin^{-1} x|\leq \pi/2$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Nothingspecial It doesn't matter.  Even with the broader criteria used in my answer, the answer is still not among the choices given.  As the other answer has revealed, it is a typographical error and the correct expression is $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \sin^{-1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$.